# How to form list of tuples from a Dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe df with the first few entries being:

```
     Input      Output
0    hj1234        2
1    gu0998        5
2    iu5678        7
3    56h781        11
```

I need to convert it to 2 separate tuples of lists, looking like this:

```
my_inputs = [
   (h, j, 1, 2, 3, 4), 
   (g, u, 0, 9, 9, 8), 
   (i, u, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
   (5, 6, h, 7, 8, 1)]'
my_outputs =[(2,),
             (5,),
             (7,),
             (11,)]
```

I have attempted this in excel using the concatenate function however the function has a maximum length to the number of characters that can be concatenated in one line. And so I am trying to do it in python. Kindly assist

Comment: That doesn't look like a list of tuples, though? At least, not the first one. What is the point of having single element tuples?

Comment: Are these meant to be test cases passed to some function for validation? Perhaps this is input to mp.Pool? I'm just trying to understand the use cases here. You can see my answer below.

Comment: Alight, these are suppose to be used as inputs and outputs for a function in neat-python and they need to be in the form stated because the XOR example needs them as I specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to, this can be done using `applymap` and `zip`.

```
a, b = map(list, zip(*df.applymap(lambda x: (x, )).values.tolist()))   
a = list(map(tuple, [a_[0] for a_ in a]))

a
# [('h', 'j', '1', '2', '3', '4'),
#  ('g', 'u', '0', '9', '9', '8'),
#  ('i', 'u', '5', '6', '7', '8'),
#  ('5', '6', 'h', '7', '8', '1')]     
b
# [(2,), (5,), (7,), (11,)]
```

---

Another option is simply handling each column separately.

```
a = list(map(tuple, df['Input']))
b = [(x, ) for x in df['Output']]

a
# [('h', 'j', '1', '2', '3', '4'),
#  ('g', 'u', '0', '9', '9', '8'),
#  ('i', 'u', '5', '6', '7', '8'),
#  ('5', '6', 'h', '7', '8', '1')]   
b
# [(2,), (5,), (7,), (11,)]
```

Comment: Thank you, however I need "a" to look like this: [('hj1234'), ('gu0998'), ('iu5678'), ('56h781')]. Note that the the commas in the list entries have been removed, therefore it is different from what you have given. Kindly assist

Comment: @Kusi I can't see anything in your comment. Also, just FYI, `('hj1234')` is NOT a tuple. Superfluous parentheses around a single expression are ignored, the result being `('hj1234')` is identical to `'hj1234'`.

Comment: Sorry I have amended the comment, I sent it before I code finish it. Please see the correction. i understand that it is not a tuple however I believe that [('hj1234'), ('gu0998'), ('iu5678'), ('56h781')] is a tuple (the whole thing not the individual entries). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Kusi See my comment above on how `('hj1234')` is not a tuple. Just go to an interpreter and type in `print(type(('hj1234')))`. It will say `<class 'str'>`. Unless you correct this fundamental misunderstanding of the language syntax,  I cannot help you further. You need to understand what you want before you ask a question.

Comment: @Kusi you also did not answer my clarifications in the comment under your question, so no wonder there is a gap between your expectations and the answer provided.

Comment: I see now that I made a mistake, it's a class of type string. I have given some clarification above. I hope it is sufficient

Comment: @Kusi No problem. So, the first is a list of strings, the second a list of tuples?

Comment: Yes...I just attempted this "a,b = map(list, zip(*df.applymap(lambda x: (x )).values.tolist()))" but it gives "a" as ['hj1234', 'gu0998','iu5678', '56h781']. But I want "a" to be [('hj1234'), ('gu0998'),('iu5678'), ('56h781')]  or [(h,j,1,2,3,4), (g,u,0,9,9,8),(i,u,5,6,7,8), (5,6,h,7,8,1)]. I think the latter would be better, can you possibly assist with this please?

Comment: Thank you very much